# iOS Core Bluetooth peripheral scan question: how to distinguish multiple devices advertising at the same time

Tags: bluetooth, ads

We have multiple devices (same kind) advertising at the same time. But in iOS, all the advertising packets are treated as one device.
Understand the reason: iOS filtered out the BLE address for privacy reasons. 
Without BLE address the advertising packets from the difference devices are exactly the same.
My question is: is it possible to use iOS core bluetooth to tell there are multiple devices are advertising?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean for "all the advertising packets are treated as one device"? Different BLE devices are not treated as one unique device: in the centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) callback you can differentiate peripherals by checking the peripheral.identifier value

Comment: I found that in some cases, the second device will not trigger didDiscover call back.